# C++ enum variables bad_alloc error

Tags: c++, memory-management, enums

I have a header file that looks like this so far:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef __Wandering2__Seed__
#define __Wandering2__Seed__
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ofMain.h"
#include "Controls.h"
#endif /* defined(__Wandering2__Seed__) */


class Seed {
public:

enum Traversal {FLOAT, WALK, FLY, ORBIT};
enum Medium {M_WATER, M_VOID, AIR};
enum SurfaceShape {SPHERE, PLANE};
enum SurfaceType {S_WATER, S_VOID, GROUND, NONE};

Traversal traversal;
Medium medium;
SurfaceShape sShape;
SurfaceType sType;

of3dPrimitive getShape();
float getRadius();

};
```

When I run my program I get the following error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc
```

I'm coming from a Java background so I'm sure that I'm allocating my enums incorrectly. If I comment out the enum variable declarations (rather than the type declarations) the program runs fine, which I assume is because there is not enough memory to allocate these four enum variables. How should I declare these enum variables so the whole class has access to them, and so the program doesn't crash?

Thanks!

edit: I would include more relevant code if there were any; I'm not calling 'new' anywhere on any of the enums. Cleaning the product with Xcode appears to have resolved the issue, so I'm not sure what the original problem was.

Comment: The declaration seems fine. Why would you use #pragma once together with #ifndef, which should contain the class declaration. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard Post the relevant code where you instantiate your class.

Comment: I don't think you've included the bad code.  `std::bad_alloc` is related to allocating memory.  Are you doing something like `new Traversal` somewhere?  That would be normally be incorrect, since you don't need to allocate enumerated types.  Treat them like `int` or `float`; just declare them and use them.

Comment: ah, yeah I just learned about the purpose of #pragma once, so hadnt updated that part of the header yet. I just cleaned the project with xcode and now it isn't crashing. I hope the problem doesn't return.

Comment: @Pancreas if it does return, run the code under a debugger to see where the bad allocation is happening. (It will be from a call to `new`)

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning the product in Xcode fixed the issue.